# define constants in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Anybody have an idea, what is the better way to define the error messages in cakephp 3.x,

I am currenlty defing error messages inline like.

```
$validator
            ->requirePresence('fname', true)
            ->notEmpty('fname')
            ->add('fname', [
                'length' => [
                    'rule' => ['maxLength', 100],
                    'message' => __('First name cannot be too long.'),
                ]
    ]);
```

but I want define constants so that it will be helpful to change message in future but I don't know better way to do it.
Does cake provide any functionality ?

Comment: This makes no sense, why would a constant be better than the translation system that allows you to change all occurrences of the same string as well by changing a single line? Also from the constant you won't get a translation. Read http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html